# data-spy links do not change on scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with data-spy for bootstrap. When page is loaded active link is the link from section 4 and when I scroll, links do not change at all. Here is my code, what is wrong with it? I do have css and js for bootstrap.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Website Builder</title>
        <!-- CSS Styles -->
        <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- JavaScript Scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') !!}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/template.js') !!}"></script>
    </head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('template')}}">WebsiteBuilder</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
                </nav>

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example there isn't enough content to actually scroll through. Also you have two unclosed `div` tags inside your `navbar` and you need to apply `position: relative` to the `body` as well.

Try adding some height to your sections to see for yourself.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
section {
  padding: 50px;
  height: 500px;
}
#section1 {
  background: #ffebee;
}
#section2 {
  background: #f44336;
}
#section3 {
  background: #d32f2f;
}
#section41 {
  background: #b71c1c;
}
#section42 {
  background: #ff1744;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebsiteBuilder</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="section1">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section2">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section3">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section41">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section42">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </section>



</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well your example works fine but I wonder why when I copied exactly same code, mine do not work. it seems to load bootstrap and jquery, I had css set up in the same way as you before you gave an answer

Comment: Without any additional information there isn't anything I can add to helping you resolve the issue.